# Usage of profilers and how to utilize the results

Tags: visual-studio, profiling, performance-testing

I have a C++ code and want to profile it. I am using the Visual Studio 2017 profiler. But how to interpret the results of "Total CPU" and "Self CPU"? I have a function with quite high "Self CPU". Also the value of "Self CPU" equals "Total CPU" for this function. What does this mean? What would be the next steps to find the performance bottle necks in the specific funtion?

Answer (score 0):

In general total CPU indicates the total time spent in the function. While self-CPU, excludes the time spent in other function that may be called.

Assume you have a function `f()` that calls 2 other funcs `g()` and `h()`.

```
void f(){
   ...
   g();
   h();
   ...
}
```

You would have `total-CPU(f)=self-CPU(f)+total-CPU(g)+total-CPU(h)` (if `g` and `h` are not used in other places of the program).

And if there is no function call in `f`,    `total-CPU(f)=self-CPU(f)`

In your specific case, if you have a function with a high self-CPU and total-CPU==self-CPU, this probably means that this function is one of your bottlenecks.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes sense for me. What would be the next steps to profile the single functions and see where the most time is spent in this specifid function? Is this possible with the Visual Studio profiler?